# How can we link a html button?

Tags: html

I would like to create an HTML button that acts like a link. So, when you click the button, it redirects to a other html webpage we want.

Currently i am doing,

```
 <form
 action="path">
 <button
 type="submit">
 login
 </submit>
 </form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link

Comment: _“I would like it to be as accessible as possible”_ - then use a link. You do not want a button to work as a link - you want a link to _look_ like a button. So format it accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is already a very similar question to this ([How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)).

Here are two other ways to do it - although crude and not valid.

`<button><a href="http://www.google.com">Button Text</a></button>`

OR

`<a href="http://www.google.com"><button>Button Text</button></a>`

OR

`<form style="display: inline" action="http://www.google.com" method="get">
  <button>Visit Website</button>
</form>`

**EDIT: As Pete pointed out, while the two methods with `<a>` and `<button>` work, the `HTML` is not valid by W3C standards. The form method is valid.**

Comment: This is totally invalid html

Comment: @Pete Instead of only telling the `<html>` is invalid and telling us we are wrong, maybe you should show the right way so that everyone can learn from it?

Comment: @Deathstorm have a look at the upvoted comment above - if you want a link, use a link and style it like a button, don't try and fudge some sort of hack, especially where accessibility is concerned

Comment: @Pete I've modified my answer.

Comment: @Deathstorm it is not working.where you enter Google url.I entered my other webpage path.It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Always use `https://` when linking a HTML button especially. Let me give you a few snippets to prove my answer:

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">Ask a Question on Stack Overflow</a>
```

If you want a hyperlink, you can use this code (I don't think regular buttons work on this website):

```
<button> <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow Button</a></button>
```

Hope this helped with your code!